# Re-populate form with JSON data

Tags: web-application, javascript, ajax, json

I re-populate form with JSON data via javascript (all data has the same origin server)

1 Wen the page load, make a request post ajax

2 The response Ajax is a:

```
Object { primary_ns: {…}, secondary_ns: {…} }
```

Here is where I do the re-populate form, looping over Object (using DOMPurify)

Does this process have some security issues?